# Expanding bottom sheet dialog fragment anchors to the bottom corner of the screen

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

According to this design for the [Bottom Sheet](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#expanding-bottom-sheet). I want to create the Bottom Sheet in the collapsed state to the bottom corner of the screen.
[Video: Expanding bottom sheets are anchored to the bottom corner of the screen](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F11GZihcMe2EcvRVEBydRCZj2_rUrmUez0%2Fexpanding-usage-chat.mp4).

How to implement this?

Comment: check this library (https://github.com/HeyAlex/CornerSheet)